# alt-tab like functionality when using terminal?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, terminal

When working in GUI we do alt-tab (or cmd-tab in mac) to switch between multiple programs, for example I am writing a text file in a text editor and then I do alt-tab to switch to already running browser to google up something then I alt-tab again to come back to keep editing.

How do you perform such "switch between" programs in command line interface - for example working with a ssh command line shell?

EDIT: I forgot to mention it, I am using ssh to connect to my university's server, and they don't have screen & tmux installed, and my account have no right to install any new apps... Is there any built-in functionality to perform this task, or any work around? For exmaple can I "minimize" running proggram and come back to regular shell interface, do some work, then display the "minimized" process again?

Comment: Have you considered using screen or tmux?

Comment: I would appeal to the powers that be to install one of the two supported applications. Failing that, you could always compile it up yourself and install it somewhere under your home directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another workaround: use the shell's job control, eg if you're editing a file, CTRL-z pauses the editor and brings you back to the shell, where you can compile, see manpages, browse the web or whatever -- and of course you can background the browser or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Screen command offers the ability to detach a long running process (or program, or shell-script) from a session and then attach it back at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

As a crude workaround, run multiple terminal windows on your computer, and alt-tab between them.

Incidentally, at the Linux console, you can switch virtual terminals with ctrl+alt+F for at least F1 through F6, commonly F8 or more (depends on how the distro sets them up). Not your case, I know, but in case future visitors should benefit.

If you are comfortable in Emacs, it allows you to run multiple independent `ansi-term` buffers.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "GNU screen" to emulate multiple terminals in one terminal.